# Why is the ImageSize setting not refreshed in the cell?

Tags: imagesize

I changed the first input and its contents in the same cell and re-executed it.

```
Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]
Plotx,{x,-1,1}, ImageSize->150}]
Plot[x,{x,-1,1}]
```

I changed it to ImageSize->150 and ran it.
However, removing this option in the cell does not return to its original size.

[image]

Why?

I want to return to its original size when removing the ImageSize option for all graphics functions such as Plot, Plot3D, etc.

Comment: When you remove the option, also remove the old image prior to reevaluating the `Plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematica preserves the last size (and other options) of the graphics in the cell. You can change this by using [`PreserveImageOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PreserveImageOptions.html).

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, PreserveImageOptions -> False]
```

To set it globally, use [`SetOptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetOptions.html).

```
SetOptions[Graphics, PreserveImageOptions -> False];
SetOptions[Graphics3D, PreserveImageOptions -> False];
SetOptions[Plot, PreserveImageOptions -> False];
SetOptions[Plot3D, PreserveImageOptions -> False];
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.